# EXPLAIN PLAN on PL/SQL with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way to debug PL/SQL, or EXPLAIN it within Oracle Databases?

I work for a large org and they have PL/SQL hell, how do I unravel thousands of PL/SQL scripts?

At the very least I want to parse out `columns`, `tables`, and `views` being accessed.  EXPLAIN PLAN works great for this with plain SQL statements.

**Other thoughts**:

1. Purchase a commercial PL/SQL parser
2. Use ANTLR to parse PL/SQL into nodes (kinda helps?)
3. Use Postgres Parser to get close? https://github.com/lfittl/libpg_query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the full answer you're looking for, but you could start with the DBA_DEPENDENCIES view to at least get the objects that the packages / procedures are dependent on.

Example

```
Select distinct
   referenced_name                  "Object name",
   referenced_type                  "Object type",
   referenced_owner                 "Owner",
   nvl(referenced_link_name,'n/a')  "DB Link"
from dba_dependencies
   where owner          = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
   and name             = 'OBJECT_NAME'
   and type             = 'PACKAGE BODY'
   and referenced_type != 'NON-EXISTENT'
   order by 3,2,1;
```